# curl capturing http status and timing the request

Tags: windows, command-line, performance, curl

I have a loop in wich I check urls from file one-by-one and want to get the status header and the execution time of every request as result.
I have two curl commands:

This one outputs the header communication (not wanted) and **at the end the http status code and time** `200 - 0,016`

```
curl -w "%{http_code} - %{time_connect}" -I -s http://superuser.com >> test_result.txt
```

This one gets the line with the **http status code from the header** and prints it to the file `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`

```
curl -v -I -s http://superuser.com | findstr /c:"HTTP" >> test_result.txt
```

How can I combine these two commands to get output from one request as this

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK - 0,016
```

so extracting the line with http header and appending the execution time without all other headers in file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a batch file

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    rem Just to test - Generate a file with URLs
    > ".\urls.txt" (
        echo http://superuser.com
        echo http://www.google.com
    )

    > ".\testResults.txt" (
        for /f "useback delims=" %%u in (".\urls.txt") do (
            set "statusCode="
            echo([%%u]
            for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=#" %%a in ('
                curl -w "##%%{time_connect}##." -I -s --url "%%~u"
                ^| findstr /l /b /c:"HTTP/" /c:"##"
            ') do if "%%b"=="." (
                setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
                echo(    !statusCode! - %%a
                endlocal
            ) else (
                set "statusCode=%%a"
            )
        )
    )
```

Just two nested loops. The first iterates over the URLs file and the second executes and processes the output of the `curl` command.

The output of `curl` command is filtered with `findstr` to retrieve only the lines with the status code and the time to connect (the output string in `-w` has been modified to locate this data in the output)

Comment: Nice. Not being on Windows (and my Windows VM not having curl available), before upvoting: can I boldly assume this creates lines like `HTTP/1.1 200 OK - 0,016`? (Heck, nice anyway.)

Comment: @Arjan, yes, and an aditional previous line with the url in square brackets (the previous `echo([%%u]`) just included to see from where `curl` is fetching the information.

Comment: yeah it works! thank you, could you please provide one command that could be used directly from cmd as an addition? with some example url

Comment: `-w '%{http_code}'` in `curl` call should return the `HTTP status code`